# Eclipse 3.5.1 update error (HTTP 503)

Tags: eclipse, http

I'm trying to update Eclipse 3.5.1 (on Gentoo Linux) from the Galileo Discovery Site and I get this error message:

```
Network connection problems encountered during search.
  Unable to access "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo".
    Error accessing site stream. [Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd]
    Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
    Error accessing site stream. [Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd]
    Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
```

It seems the 503 error code is intended to [stop software from constantly downloading this file](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic) from w3.org. But how do I persuade Eclipse to stop requesting it?

Comment: I am suffering from the same problem but on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx, Eclipse version is 3.5.2. Yours is probably 3.5.1 and not 5.3.1?

Comment: You could mirror the entire site to a local server and then create a HOSTS file entry for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several updates of Eclipse, the supporting software and libraries this now works.
The correct way to update from the Galileo site is via "Help/Install New Software" or "Help/Update".
The route via "Help/Software Updates/Find and Install/Search for new..." fails because the update-site format has changed.